# Вывести все минимальные числа

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Есть такое задание: в массиве найти минимальное число. Если минимальных чисел несколько, то присвоить им среднее арифметическое исходного массива и вывести измененный массив.

Собственно, я это все сделал, однако хочу оптимизировать код, чтобы было меньше строк.

Я не прошу писать код за меня, я хочу, чтобы меня подтолкнули в правильном направлении. На другом форуме говорят, что можно все реализовать через 2 цикла, но я уже 2 дня думаю и никак не могу сообразить, как сделать.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    srand(time(0));

    double array[10];
    double minNumber = 0.0, average = 0.0;
    int counter(0);

    //Заполнение и вывод массива
    printf("Исходный массив:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        array[i] = 1 + rand() % 9;  //Заполнение массива случайными числами от 1 до 9
        printf("%.2f ", array[i]);      

        average = average + array[i];   //Суммируем все элементы массива
        if (i == 9)                     //Когда массив заполнится, находим среднее арифметическое
            average = average / 10;
    }

    minNumber = array[0];   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (minNumber > array[i]) { //Сравнение элементов массива
            minNumber = array[i];   //Присвоим minNumber минимальное значение
            }   
    }
    printf("\nМинимальное значение: %.2f\n", minNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == minNumber) {
            counter++;
            array[i] = average;
        }
    }

    if(counter >= 2)
    {
        printf("\nИзмененный массив: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%.2f ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Обычно, чем ниже квалификация программиста, тем сильнее у него желание "оптимизировать" код, стараясь, в частности, все запихнуть в один цикл. В результате код становится трудно-читаемым, а конструкции программы сильно перегружены.  Старайтесь в первую очередь писать логически ясный код.

Comment: Кстати сказать, ваш код не соответствует описанию задания. Вы заменяете средним значением минимальный элемент даже в случае, когда такой минимальный элемент единственный.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow мм, оптимизировать хочу исключительно из-за интереса.
Хм.. Разве? Ведь ,если в массиве только 1 минимальное число, то counter будет меньше двух и цикл не сработает.

Comment: Вот ваш цикл, который выполняет безусловную операцию относительно переменной counter     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == minNumber) {
            counter++;
            array[i] = average;
        }
    }

Comment: @MikhailYakovlev, просто перенесите проверку на минимальность в первый цикл (присвоив изначально `minNumber`-у `10`). В качестве упражнения - найдите еще одну ненужную (не в том месте) замедляющую операцию в вашем коде.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow не совсем понимаю. Я же ставлю условие, что элемент массива = переменной, в которой хранится минимальное значение.

Comment: @acade да, я думал об этом. Ну, о поиска минимального числа при заполнении массива. Даже код писал, однако не получилось! Подумаю еще, как это сделать нужно. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Mikhail Yakovlev Ну, так по условию вами самим написанного задания такая замена должна происходить только в случае, когда минимальных элементов больше одного. А вы это делаете в любом случае.

Comment: Во первых у вас массив для типов double, а вы заполняете целыми. Так определитесь какой тип массива вам нужен

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ах и в самом деле! Спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я уже писал в комментарии к вашему вопросу, что,, обычно, чем ниже квалификация программиста, тем сильнее у него желание "оптимизировать" код, стараясь, в частности, все запихнуть в один цикл. В результате код становится трудно-читаемым, а конструкции программы сильно перегружены. Старайтесь в первую очередь писать логически ясный код

Трудно-читаемый код - это всегда источник различных багов, и к тому же такой код трудно модифицировать

У вас в задании написано:

> в массиве найти минимальное число. **Если минимальных чисел
>   несколько**, то присвоить им среднее арифметическое исходного массива
>   и вывести измененный массив.

Вот и следуйте букве этого задания. То есть вы сначала должны определить минимальное значение элементов в массиве, а также сколько элементов массива содержит это минимальное значение.

И только в случае, если таких элементов больше одного, то тогда заменить значения таких элементов средним значением. То есть эта часть программы выполняется только при одном условии.

Не надо делать в данной момент программы то, что в ней не требуется делать. Иначе такой код, в котором что-то делается, что в данный момент не требуется делать, будет вызывать вопросы и недоумения.

Поэтому в первую очередь надо думать не о пресловутой "оптимизации", а о качественно написанном коде логически ясным.

Старайтесь не использовать в коде магических чисел таких, как, например, `10`. Используйте именованные константы.

Вот как может выглядеть ваш код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    double a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    int MAX_VALUE = 9;

    for ( auto &item : a ) item = 1 + std::rand() % MAX_VALUE;

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double min   = a[0];
    size_t count = 1;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < min )
        {
            min = a[i];
            count = 1;
        }
        else if ( not( min < a[i] ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    if ( count > 1 )
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for ( const auto &item : a ) sum += item;

        double average = sum / N;

        for ( auto &item : a )
        {
            if ( item == min ) item = average;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может быть, к примеру, следующим:

```
3 9 6 3 2 6 9 2 8 9 
3 9 6 3 5.7 6 9 5.7 8 9
```

То есть в данном конкретном случае два элемента массива содержат минимальное значение, равное 2. А потмоу значения этих двух элементов массива заменяется средним арифметическим значением.

Итак, программа сначала ищет минимальное значение и количество элементов, содержащих это минимальное значение

```
    double min   = a[0];
    size_t count = 1;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] < min )
        {
            min = a[i];
            count = 1;
        }
        else if ( not( min < a[i] ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
```

И лишь затем, если число элементов, содержащих найденное минимальное значение, больше 1, то происходит замена значений этих элементов средним значением.

```
    if ( count > 1 )
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        for ( const auto &item : a ) sum += item;

        double average = sum / N;

        for ( auto &item : a )
        {
            if ( item == min ) item = average;
        }
    }
```

Теперь, когда имеется логически ясный код, то его легко "оптимизировать", как вы к тому стремитесь. Можно исключить отдельный цикл, который подсчитывает сумму всех элементов массива для вычисления далее среднего арифметического. (На самом деле это будет кажущаяся оптимизация, так как теперь, даже если в массиве имеется только один элемент с минимальным значением, происходит безусловное вычисление суммы всех элементов.)

В этом случае программа будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    double a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    int MAX_VALUE = 9;

    for ( auto &item : a ) item = 1 + std::rand() % MAX_VALUE;

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    double min   = a[0];
    size_t count = 1;
    //  preliminarily calculating the sum of all elements of the array
    //  used in the if ( count > 1 ) code block to escape a redundant loop
    double sum = a[0];

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        sum += a[i];

        if ( a[i] < min )
        {
            min = a[i];
            count = 1;
        }
        else if ( not( min < a[i] ) )
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    if ( count > 1 )
    {
        double average = sum / N;

        for ( auto &item : a )
        {
            if ( item == min ) item = average;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Желательно перед циклом, который вычисляет сумму элементов, поместить комментарий, объясняющий, почему мы решили сделать это имеено в этом месте программы.

Answer (score 0):

> Собственно, я это все сделал, однако хочу оптимизировать код, чтобы было меньше строк.

Разделите ваш код на функции, после чего будет видно где требуется провести оптимизацию.

```
 #include <iostream>

// В (double array[]) и (double * array) - эквивалентные записи.

void fillArray(double * array) 
{
    //Заполнить массив
    ...
}

void showArray(double * array)
{
    // Отобразить массив
}

double arichmeticAverage(double * array)
{
    double average = 0;
    //Найти среднее арифметическое
    ...
    return average;
}

double minNumber (double * array)
{
    double min = 0;
    //Поиск минимально значения
    ...
    return min;
}

double something (double * array)
{
    // Something
    return ...;
}

int main()
{
    double array[100];
    fillArray(array);
    showArray(array);
    double average = arichmeticAverage(array);
    double min = minNumber(array);
    ...
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пока что функции я знаю только теоретически. Понимаю, как они работают, знаю синтаксис, но практики никакой не было. Да и вряд-ли я ЗНАЮ, в самоучителе главу о них читал, когда в больнице был.
Я стараюсь читать свой код и разбивать его на действия, которые происходят.

Comment: И почему вы это считаете оптимизацией?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мм, я, скорее написал неправильно. Сократить количество кода хочу. Хотя, после сообщения Formonder я хочу попробовать и через функции написать )

Comment: Я не считаю данный код оптимизацией программы, это рекомендация - декомпозировать задачу.

Comment: @Formonder я плохо выражаю свои мысли ) Вы, вроде, в своем коде выделили функции и их назначение. Мне интересно будет в таком виде написать программу! Я понимаю, что это не оптимизация, но читать такой код реально приятнее

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам с двумя циклами. Учитесь пользоваться контейнерами, с ними и ошибок меньше и код получается проще. Можно было бы конечно обойтись и без них, но код получился бы намного сложнее и если не писать свой список, то пришлось бы добавлять ещё один массив того же размера что и исходный (это хорошо у вас 10 элементов... а если 10 тысяч? :) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  const int arraySize = 10;
  srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

  std::array<double, arraySize> dataArray; // исходный массив
  double minNumber = 1e9; // инициализируем заведомо бОльшим значением
  double average = 0.0;
  double currentData; // просто для ускорения работы
  std::list<unsigned> indexes; // список индексов минимальных чисел

  std::cout << "Исходный массив:" << std::endl;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++) {
    currentData = 1 + rand() % 9; // генерируем случайное число от 1 до 9
    dataArray[i] = currentData;  //Заполнение массива
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << currentData << ' '; // выводим массив
    if (minNumber > currentData) {
      minNumber = currentData; // нашли новый минимум
      indexes.clear(); // очищаем ранее найденные индексы минимума
      indexes.push_back(i); // запоминаем индекс нового минимума
    }
    // далее можно было бы поставить обычное равенство, но с вещественным числами лучше поступать примерно так:
    else if (fabs(minNumber-currentData)<1e-9) {
      // нашли ещё один элемент с текущим минимумом
      indexes.push_back(i);
    }
    average += currentData; // внутри цикла только накапливаем, проверка заполнения не нужна
  }
  // среднее значение получаем после цикла
  average /= dataArray.size();
  std::cout << std::endl << "Минимальное значение: "
            << std::setprecision(2) << minNumber << std::endl;
  // теперь меняем массив и сразу печатаем
  std::cout << "Измененный массив:" << std::endl;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < dataArray.size(); i++) {
    if (i == indexes.front()) { // текущий элемент массива - минимум?
      dataArray[i] = average; // меняем его
      indexes.pop_front(); // удаляем изменённый элемент из списка индексов
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << dataArray[i] << ' '; // выводим массив
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за потраченное время! Насчет читабельного кода - Вы абсолютно правы! Да, сперва мне стоит научиться именно этому, а оптимизация кода уже потом.
Еще раз большое спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Ну, например, вот через два цикла(как вы хотели)

```
double array[10];
size_t  quantity = 0;
// тут инициализируем array[0]
double minNumber = array[0], average = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    // инициализируем array[i]
    average += array[i];
    if (minNumber > array[i])
        minNumber = array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    if (i >= 10 ) {
        if (quantity < 2)
            break;
        printf("%.2f ", array[i % 10]);
    }
    else if ( array[i] == minNumber) {
        ++quantity;
        array[i] = average / 10;
    }
}
```

p.s. если ваш массив будет содержать целые, то вам нужен массив для типов `int`, а не  `double`

Comment: Это понятно! Но среднее арифметическое должно быть double. В половине случаев будет десятичная часть. Сейчас разберу Ваш код. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: я изначально пробовал искать минимальное во время заполнения массива. Однако, при выполнении программы в переменной minNumber я получаю бред аля -987687687576857578.68. Потому и не стал так делать.<br/>
Как я понимаю, такое получается потому, что array[0] до заполнения неизвестен и minNumber получает бредовое значение.<br/>
(не знаю, как выделить код в комментария)<br/>
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) <== я правильно понимаю, что тут Вы сначала считаете количество минимальных в первых 10 итерациях, а потом проверяете quantity на количество?

Comment: Да, вы правильно понели: для работы с массивом, нужно его инициализировать, а так как вы работу начинаете с первого элемента, то в самом начале нужно инициализировать этот первый элемент, не то получите мусор

Comment: не понимаю. Но у Вас в коде массив инициализирован, но не заполнен, при этом minNumber получает значение первого элемента ДО заполнения массива. Мой компилятор присваивает minNumber мусор. Мне нужно 
    'minNumber = array[0];'
писать в первом цикле, чтобы не было мусора, но тогда он будет сравнивать только первый элемент со всеми остальными. не могу внятно объяснить.

Comment: Я же в комментариях писал: тут инициализировать ... Инициализируйте сами как хотите

Comment: аа, я Вас не так понял. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, примите, нажав на галочку, и пожалуйста.  Когда изучите С++, такой код можно будет написать пару строчками